# MOSFET amplifier using single rail DC

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, audio, dc

Back in the day I built high power push-pull audio amplifiers using a few MOSFETs and a split-rail DC supply (12-0-12v, 16A) - and I fully understood the circuit.

What I’m tying to understand is how one can build an amplifier using only a single rail DC - say I only have Ground and +24v.

How is it possible to drive a speaker IN and OUT without both a positive and negative voltage from a common ground?

Comment: Call 12 V your new ground and voilla.

Comment: Sure, but how would I do that and retain the ability to draw reasonable current? A resistor voltage divider wouldn’t work... I’m new. Help me out.  :)

Comment: The problem is that I don’t have a decent center-tapped transformer at my disposal. Could I split the voltage in a different way?

Comment: Research "virtual ground" circuits.

Comment: You could do a bridge topology, with double the load voltage. A tiny negative issue is the THD goes up by the sqrt of 2.

Comment: In the good ole days they would put a large capacitor to block DC to the speaker, but the down side was severe phase shifting in the low bass region.

Comment: @Sparky256 would you mind giving me a little info (basic how-to) on the bridge topology? Are you talking about splitting the AC using two half-wave rectifiers?

Comment: Looks like I need to create a more specific question about split-rail DC from single output transformer.

Comment: A bridge topology means you build two identical amplifiers, with one getting an inverted signal from the source. The speaker is connected between the two amp outputs. Since both are biased to 1/2 Vcc supply the speaker gets only the amplified signal. Very common in car stereos to get the most out of 12 volts.

Comment: @Sparky256 love it!

Comment: This link is the best I can do for you. The amplifiers MUST have identical specs or severe THD will occur.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridged_and_paralleled_amplifiers#Bridged_amplifier

Comment: Automotive 24W Amps /ch would use a Class D full bridge IC